# android how to set notifySetDataChanged() for an ArrayList

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I'm trying to refresh a `ListView` contents when I go back to the activity from another activity. It only refresh contents when I go back further to main app screen and come back.

This is my **Activity** where I set the `ListView` and it's adapter:

```
public static final String ID = "Id";
public static final String iidd = "iidd";
private static final String DESC = "Description";

private AppCompatDelegate delegate;
Cursor c;
ListView listFood;
SimpleAdapter myAdapter;
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> names = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Integer i_d;
Integer iddd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityfood_main);

    listFood = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewF);
    listFood.setOnItemClickListener(viewFoodListener);

    // database read
    DatabaseConnectorFood db = new DatabaseConnectorFood(this);
    db.open();
    c = db.getFoodData();

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        data.put("Description", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")));
        data.put("Serving_Size", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Serving_Size")));
        names.add(data);
    }
    db.close();

    myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, names, R.layout.list_food,
            new String[] {"Description", "Serving_Size"},
            new int[] {R.id.ViewFoodNotesOne, R.id.ViewFoodNotesTwo});

    listFood.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

I tried to add this under `onResume()` but it doesn't work

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

**EDIT:** i followed the suggestion by answers below doing as follow, but with no results:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    DatabaseConnectorFood db = new DatabaseConnectorFood(this);
    db.open();
    c = db.getFoodData();

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
        data.put("Description", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Description")));
        data.put("Serving_Size", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Serving_Size")));
        names.add(data);
    }
    db.close();

    myAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, names, R.layout.list_food,
            new String[] {"Description", "Serving_Size"},
            new int[] {R.id.ViewFoodNotesOne, R.id.ViewFoodNotesTwo});

    // Set the Adapter into SimpleCursorAdapter
    listFood.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**SOLVED:** added `names.clear();` to the code over here, above everything, to clear the `ListView` first as @Rami suggested, and it works! thanks

Comment: You need to update your adapter data before calling *notifyDataSetChanged()*.

Comment: I update SQLite items on the next activity mentioned, where i have some EditTexts with a save button, the save button is sent to DatabaseConnector's UpdateNoteFood() which I've added to my original post

Comment: Updating the adapter data is different then updating your SQLite db. You need to clear your *names* list and reload the data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To refresh your list, you need to clear your data (`names`) then reload it again from the database.

2) `onResume()` method is frequently called. For better performance, i suggest you to use `onActivityResult()` instead, while you update your data from the childs activities.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // refresh your list here.

}
```

In this case, don't forget to use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is used to tell the `ListView` that the **items in the dataset** have changed.

You need to modify the actualy dataset for it to have any visual effects, since by just invoking the method the same values will be displayed before and after the method was called.

If you want to keep this approach, you would need to *query the database again* in `onResume` to reload your data. *Then* call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 1):

onCreate doesn't called when you go back with onBackPressed(); you need to put all logick with setting data to adapter in onResume() method

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead of a `SimpleAdapter`. It will take care of all the details for you when the data changes in your database.